# How to link chart and javascript cell to have the same chart object as reference

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Recently started exploring Cloud Datalab.I have implemented GeoCharts and now i wanted to place event handling and extend chart functionality.I couldn't figure out how to link %%charts cell and %%javascript cell to have the same chart reference and perform event handling.Can someone please help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible right now using %%chart. You could potentially create your own extended form of %%chart ([source](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/blob/master/sources/lib/datalab/gcp/datalab/_chart.py)) that includes custom Javascript in the _HTML_TEMPLATE but that is non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Graham Wheeler , Is there any link where can i check what is in build pipeline for the next release of Datalab?

Comment: We release straight from the master branch so you can see the commits that way: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datalab/commits/master

Comment: When i'm trying to commit the notebook from appengine console it is giving me the error  "The user request is invalid. Please check your URL and try again." . How can we resolve this?